# API call returning extra unnecessary HTML header information

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, api

Hi I am making a call to an API and it is returning

```
[{"ActorID":1,"ActorName":"dfdsf","ActorOccupation":0,"ActorLevel":3,"VsRank":10,"PVP_Vs":0,"FightTotalCount":"0","WinCount":"0"},
{"ActorID":2,"ActorName":"sdsf","ActorOccupation":0,"ActorLevel":0,"VsRank":10,"PVP_Vs":0,"FightTotalCount":"0","WinCount":"0"}]


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="GetRankingList.aspx?pvptype=1&amp;sid=1&amp;tm=20130821160000&amp;auth=77c9b582c3aed3d3974400cfb118fe4b" id="form1">
                <div class="aspNetHidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZLSAAAtd4/lj1u6b0GjPWM+p3i9tqI6sq+xDrRw2cAv3" />
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

All I want is the simple JSON array object. I did not write this API, but does anybody know how I can perhaps just specify I want the object itself. I already specify

```
format : "json"
```

as a parameter when I make this call. The value gets returned no matter how I make the call (Ajax, browser, etc).

Comment: If the output below the actual JSON is fixed, you can simply chop it off

Comment: Ask the writers of the API to fix their thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another (convoluted) solution is to run it through this HTML Sanitizer API -

https://www.mashape.com/pbkwee/html-sanitizer#!endpoint-HTML-Sanitizer

I ran your output above and it almost removed everything, except it padded div tags at both ends (well you can remove them)